# Question tag: Either you or he is mistaken, ____?

Tags: tag-questions, correlating-conjunctions, proximity-agreement

What is the appropriate tag to add to the end of the following statement?

Either you or he is mistaken, ______ ?

As is evident from the is, there are grounds for saying that the so-called proximity rule, that with subjects in either + or frame the closet noun to the verb determines whether the verb is singular or plural, is applied to this statement.

On this basis I tend to presumably conclude that the tag should in turn be isn't he?.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably safest to bring the emphasis of the question back onto yourself:

> Either you or he is mistaken, **I assume**?

With two people involved, neither of which are yourself, and only one of which is present, you are only going to get into an argument which is nothing to do with you.

Answer (score -1):

Though the proximity rule is believable, I think when you have 'or,' the question tag is difficult to form. Because question tags take one subject and ask for the opposite result.

> You are going to the US, aren't you?

There is only one subject and we add negation with it to form a question tag. But when you have two entities, forming a question tag is not possible, IMO.

---

Nevertheless, there's an *Indian way* to do that -

> Either you or he is mistaken, ***isn't it?***

Indians form a question tag with *isn't it,'* for *almost everything!* Probably, because we consider everything as an event represented by *'it'* (irrespective of the number of subjects we have in a sentence!).

Comment: Learn something new every day... I always thought the London "innit" came from Turkish/Cypriot, not Indian. "Either you or he is mistaken, innit?"

Comment: @Tetsujin
Can the variant 'innit' also be non-standardly used as alternant of any question tag?

Comment: There was a period, thankfully it's getting less popular, when some people's every utterance ended with 'innit' whether appropriate or not. "Do you like my new shirt, innit" "Let's go out to dinner, innit" It got really bad for a time :/

Comment: Seriously, I would avoid it like the plague... even as an abbreviation of 'isn't it'.

Comment: IndE *isn't it* and BrE *innit* are examples of **invariant tags**.  They're called invariant because they don't change form to match the rest of the sentence.  There is a Standard English invariant tag as well: "right?"

Comment: @snailboat - ahh, ty for putting a name to it. I can now add that, the old 70's "you know" & the 90's variant "like" to my list. *That's cool, innit, you know, like, right?*